# Significance of /sys/block/sd*/sd*/size

Tags: filesystems, partition, mbr

Disk size `/sys/block/sda/size` is always correct but the partition size `/sys/block/sda/sda2/size` is not correct if the partition type is extended, boot, etc, due to this I rely on reading MBR to get the correct partition size.

What does the value in `/sys/block/sd*/sd*/size` file signify?
What is the correct way to get the partition size apart from reading MBR or using commands?

Example:

```
nyc@nyc:~/Documents$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1 TiB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x13ce1e72

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048 1881196543 1881194496  897G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1881196544 2147483647  266287104  127G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1881198592 1983643647  102445056 48.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6       1983645696 2076295167   92649472 44.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       2090141696 2139455487   49313792 23.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb8       2139457536 2147483647    8026112  3.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
nyc@nyc:~/Documents$ cat /sys/block/sdb/size 
2147483648
nyc@nyc:~/Documents$ cat /sys/block/sdb/sdb2/size 
2
```

Comment: Might be better if you show an example

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 because that partition is extended partition, which contains logical partitions. Here 2 denotes the number of `512 byte` sectors, or we can say that it has 1 `1K` block. You can use the command `lsblk` which will give you output as:

```
sdb2   8:3    0     1K  0 part
```

which shows that it is an extended partition.